# How to stop nested directive execution from an outer directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-compile

I'm creating a directive which will restrict HTML access if some condition are not met. Unfortunately issue arises when inner directives get called before inner HTML is changed and compiled.

Is it possible to stop nested directive execution from any outer directive?

Example (see console): http://jsfiddle.net/xaQzb/14/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
  <outer-element>
    <inner-element>
    </inner-element>
  </outer-element>
</div>
```

App

```
angular.module('testApp', []);

var app = angular.module('testApp');

app
  .directive('outerElement', ['$compile', function($compile) {

    function linker(scope, element) {
      element[0].innerHTML = 'Replaced HTML and should not execute anything inside';
      $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    }

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: false,
      link: linker
    }
  }]);

app
  .directive('innerElement', function() {

    function linker(scope, element) {
      console.log('Directive has been called');
    }

    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: false,
      link: linker
    }
  });
```

Comment: I guess best and easiest way is just add ng-if to inner-directive and set it from outer-element

Comment: @PetrAveryanov I don't want to touch inner element, that is why I'm building an outside element directive which would do that for me

Answer (score 0):

ngIf will help you:

```
  <div ng-if="condition">
    <inner-element>
    </inner-element>
  </div>
```

Comment: This `ng-if` is exactly the thing I'm trying to replace.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`terminal: true`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-terminal-) directive option.